# Converting my marks from Indian to US grading system makes it appear low

Tags: phd, united-states, grades, india

My profile:

- BSMS from IISER Trivandrum (7.67/10 overall; 8.5 in MS alone).
- MBA from MANAGE Hyderabad (74%).

I'm applying to US universities for coming Fall 2022, for PhD in Marketing. However when my MBA marks get converted to the US 4.0 scale, it is low. The topper in my batch was 83% and we had an absolute grading system as well. I'm worried about this affecting the application. What should I do?

Comment: Do mention somewhere in your application (may be SOP/personal essay) that the topper was 83%.

Comment: _when my MBA marks get converted to the US 4.0 scale_ - Who is doing this conversion and how?  I usually don't see converted grades for applicants from India.

Comment: @Nachiket From context I assume you mean "topper" to mean the top ranked student in the class. This meaning would not be apparent to most US English speakers and I wouldn't use that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight numeric conversions between grading systems of different countries can be very misleading. I suspect that the people that are responsible for doing this understand that. In some places, like the US, getting "top marks" is common, even when it isn't easy. In other places, and I suspect India is one, it is very uncommon to get such marks. This fact, that professors in different systems grade quite differently, is responsible for the issue.

Unfortunately, some places require the candidate to provide a translation, though they normally don't have the experience to do so "wisely". Other places have professionals provide an interpretation of grades that can be more accurate and useful.

If you don't need to provide the translation yourself, then don't be overly concerned. People understand the issue. If you do have to provide the translation, then find a place to give a bit of context to the grades along with a faithful translation.

The SoP probably is not the right place as it has a more important function.

But for US admissions, GRE is only a small part of the overall evaluation of a candidate. Letters of recommendation are highly valued here, perhaps more than in India. And make the SoP future based, detailing plans for grad study and (important) beyond.